# Passport Local Strategy Not working with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, authentication

I'm trying to set up login and authentication with passport.js, and I'm having trouble with my login function.

The local strategy doesn't show any errors but it also doesn't set the req.user property or the expose req.isAuthenticated().

I've linked to the full repo, but here is my local strategy.

````
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

var User = require("./models/user");

module.exports = function() {
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

  passport.use(
    "login",
    new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "No user has that username!" });
        }
        user.checkPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password." });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );
};```
````

Here's the repo:

[Link to my repo](http://%20https://github.com/mcewen87/rush-app)

Comment: Hi - I tried to click on your repot see your implementation of .checkPassword (as I am curious how you get that to work), but the link is not working. Upvoted, to encourage someone to answer.